# Use of pipe within backtick command

Tags: perl

I'm having an issue with some code and I'm wondering if anyone can assist.

Basically I'm trying to execute an isql query against a database and assign it to a scalar variable. The isql command makes use of the column seperator which is defined as the pipe symbol.

So I have it set-up as such:

```
my $command = "isql -S -U -s| -i";
my $isql_output = `$command`;
```

The isql command works in isolation but when issued as a backtick it stops at the pipe. I've tried concatenating the `$command` string using sub-strings, using single quotes and backslash escaping items such as `-s\"\|\"` to no avail. I've also tried using `qx` instead of backticks.

Unfortunately I'm currently using an older version of perl (v5.6.1) with limited scope for upgrade so I'm not sure if I can resolve this.

Answer (score 4):

You have to quote the `|` in a way that the shell does not recognize it as a special character. Two ways:

1. Put the `-s|` into single quotes: `'-s|'`. Perl will leave single quotes inside double quoted strings alone and pass them to the shell unmodified.
2. Escape the `|` with two backslashes: `-s\\|`. Why two? The first one is seen by Perl telling it to pass the next character through unmodified. Therefore the shell sees `-s\|` and does something very similar: it sees the single `\` and knows not to treat the next char, `|`, special.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Moritz. However if I use single quotes I get an error that ''' is not recognised as an internal or external command. And if I use double backslash it then states that '-ixxx' is not recognised as an internal command tc. Printing $command shows the single backslash in the text.

Comment: @user1891588 did the answer help? If so, you should accept it by clicking the green arrow to the left.

Comment: @user1891588: Well, please copy & paste what you've changed it to and which still does not work if you want further help. I cannot read minds.

Comment: my $command="isql -Sserver -Uuser -Ppassword -s'|' -w4096 –i$file";
print "$command\n";
my $isql_output=`$command`;

D:\temp>backtick.pl
isql -Sserver -Uuser -Ppassword -s'|' -w4096 -id:\temp\file.sql
''' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ah... Windows and cmd.exe. Sorry, but I cannot help you with that.

Comment: my $command="isql -Sserver -Uuser -Ppassword -s\\| -w4096 -i$file";
print "$command\n";
my $isql_output=`$command`;

D:\temp>backtick.pl
isql -Sserver -Uuser -Ppassword -s\| -w4096 -id:\temp\file.sql
'-w4096' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Is it works with other symbols instead '|' ?, example for -s =

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the command is being executed through a shell.
You can avoid this by passing the command and arguments in a list rather than a single string.
The backtick construct does not support that, so you would need to use the `open()` function instead.
I haven't tested the following code but it gives the idea:

```
my @command = (qw(isql -Sserver -Uuser -Ppassword -s| -w4096), '–i' . $file);
print join(' ', @command), "\n";
open(my $fh, '-|', @command)
  or die "failed to run isql command: $@\n";
my @isql_output = <$fh>;
close($fh);
my $isql_output = $isql_output[0]; chomp($isql_output);
```

If you're working with a 15 year old version of Perl (which Oracle users tend to do) I'm not sure this will all be supported.  For instance, you may need to write `chop` instead of `chomp`.

UPDATE: the problem is not the Perl version, but this construct not being supported on Windows, [according to the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens).  This must be qualified: I use Perl on Cygwin and it works fine there, but I don't know whether you can use Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but yep it's not working. Can't use an undefined value as filehandle reference which looks to be version related.

Comment: Odd ... if $fh is undefined, it should have `die()`d.  Makes sure you start your script with `use strict; use warnings;` to detect any other problems with undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes should work. Try to run test perl script:

```
my $cmd = "./test.sh -S -U -s '|' -i";
print `$cmd`;
```

With test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $@
```

Output should be `-S -U -s | -i`

Comment: I get the same error. Printing $command outputs the single quotes but the backtick exection gives me a ''' error that it's not recognised as an internal or external command.